# Override __new__() to replace class method with default arguments

Tags: python, subclassing, factory-method

Below is a slightly lengthy example for a class `ProgressPrinter` with two different implementations, depending on whether the file descriptor it is used with is connected to a console or something else. Users are create instances by calling `ProgressPrinter.create()`, which has a handy default argument:

```py
import sys

class ProgressPrinter:
    def __init__(self, file):
        self._file = file

    def print_progress(self, message):
        raise NotImplementedError

    @classmethod
    def create(cls, file=sys.stderr):
        if file.isatty():
            return TTYProgressPrinter(file)
        else:
            return NoTTYProgressPrinter(file)

class TTYProgressPrinter(ProgressPrinter):
    def print_progress(self, message):
        # Image some fancy stuff with ANSI escape codes.
        pass

class NoTTYProgressPrinter(ProgressPrinter):
    def print_progress(self, message):
        print(message, file=self._file)
```

What is the best way to rewrite this so that, instead of calling `ProgressPrinter.create([file])`, users could directly call `ProgressPrinter([file])` with same result?

I tried around with overwriting `__new__()` and even writing a metaclass but none of it worked (Lots of `TypeError: object() takes no parameters` and `TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'file'` and even a `RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object`).

**Update**: Removed redundant code in example.
**Update**: Make implementations actually subclass the base class.

Comment: Have you considered making `ProgressPrinter` a function instead of a class?

Comment: Search SO for `[python] factory pattern` you'll find lots of examples.

Comment: @GreenCloakGuy Actually, yes. But I would like to use `ProgressPrinter` as a type annotation (it's passed around a lot). Actually, I haven't tried, but I think that would't work if it were a function. But it would definitely be a simple and effective solution to my problem!

Comment: @Barmar Uuuhh, maybe link an answer you think particularly fits my question? I have no problem closing this question with _already answered_.

Comment: `ProgressPrinter` doesn't need to be a function, but `ProgressPrinter.create` certainly can be. Note that you aren't using `cls` in the definition, and it's slightly odd to make any part of a class require knowledge of its own children.

Comment: @chepner `create()` isn't using it's argument `cls`, that is true. Using subclasses/implementation from within a type is pretty standard in functional and also OO programming. The Java SDK has lots of examples of this, see e.g. `ByteBuffer.java`.

Comment: Python isn't Java; you don't need to use classes nearly as much in Python as you do in Java. Specifically, there's no need to define a class for the sole purpose of providing a method; just define a regular function.

Answer (score 2):

> What is the best way to rewrite this so that, instead of calling `ProgressPrinter.create([file])`, users could directly call `ProgressPrinter([file])` with same result?

Just refrain. What you really want is that users feel comfortable with your code. When I see `ProgressPrinter.create([file])`, I can assume a factory which will create objects related to `ProgressPrinter` but of possibly different classes. You want them to be subclasses which is fine.

But when I see `ProgressPrinter([file])`, I expect an object from *exactly* `ProgressPrinter` class and not member of a subclass. That means that this code will be harder to read and understand, what you certainly do not want. I know that Python allows it, and I even know how to do it. But it is not natural because programmers are not expected to do it.

The rule is *follow well established patterns*. You can either use delegation to sub-object (**not** sub-classes) as suggested by @Barmar, or stick to the factory pattern. But please do not use *anti-patterns*...

---

If you really want to do it, the trick is to build and configure an object of the proper subclass in new. But you must use `Object.__new__` to build an object of a subclass. If you just use the standard creation, you would recurse into `ProgressPrinter.__new__` leading to a stack overflow.

The minimum change would then be to replace your `__init__` method with this `__new__` one:

```
def __new__(cls, file):
    if (cls == ProgressPrinter):                   # delegate sub object creation
        return ProgressPrinter.create(file)
    pp = super(ProgressPrinter, cls).__new__(cls)  # trick to avoid recursion
    pp.file = file
    return pp
```

You could also remove the create method and copy its code directly into `__new__`

But this is only to show you the possibilities of the Python language and I still strongly urge you **not** to use that in production code and stick to a nicer factory pattern. Future maintainers would certainly blame you for using this *anti-pattern*!

Comment: Thanks for the question. My question arose from the urge to understand how I could do this, even if it was agains Python conventions. I don't think I agree that returning a subclass is confusing. It's an implementation detail and it doesn't violate any rules of OO programming.

Comment: @Feuermurmel: it is indeed an implementation detail when you use the factory pattern. But in any OO language, `new Clazz(..)` or `Clazz(...)` is expected to build a `Clazz` object. It is not really confusing for the language itself (Python does allow it) but for future readers.

Comment: Oh, no thank you for belittling me. I'm trying to understand what the interactions between the metaclasses `__call__()` and the classes `__new__()` and `__init__()` are and thought this was a good exercise to get a better understanding. In my project, I'm currently using the variant I posted in my question I'm only going to change that if I see good reasons to do so.

Comment: @Feuermurmel: that is the reason why I posted that code using `__new__` :-). But I still wanted to warn future readers that is was an anti-pattern. BTW metaclasses is an even more advanced tool which is not required here. They are intended to provide a consistent but not standard behaviour among a collection of classes that are not a direct hierarchy.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a working example to get you off the ground.

```py
class IceCream:
    def __new__(ignored_cls, flavor):
        # Here we actually return a new instance,
        # not update one created for us as in __init__.
        # We ignore the class because we're not returning
        # instances of it directly; we could merge this class
        # and IceCreamBase, but then we'd have to override __new__
        # in both Vanilla and Chocolate back to the default impl.
        if flavor == 'vanilla':
            return Vanilla()
        else:
            return Chocolate()

class IceCreamBase:
    def eat(self):
        return "Yum! It was %s" % self.flavor

class Vanilla(IceCreamBase):
    @property
    def flavor(self):
        return "vanilla"

class Chocolate(IceCreamBase):
    @property
    def flavor(self):
        return "chocolate"
```

Now we can do this:

```
>>> IceCream('vanilla').eat()
'Yum! It was vanilla'
>>> IceCream('other').eat()
'Yum! It was chocolate'
>>>
```

At this point you must have noticed, that `IceCream` is just a *function* in disguise, called in a convoluted way.

I would suggest that you used a factory function (not method) in your case, if returning a right value for the arguments (and not some other internal state) is what you need.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! What speaks agains a factory method? I would definitely prefer a plain function over this. :) Partly because it breaks the assumption that `IceCream` can be used as a type annotation.

Answer (score 0):

Do it by delegation, not subclassing, choosing the implementation class in the `__init__` method.

```
import sys

class ProgressPrinter:
    def __init__(self, file=sys.stderr):
        self._file = file
        self.printer = ProgressPrinter.create(file)

    def print_progress(self, message):
        self.printer.print_progress(message)

    @classmethod
    def create(cls, file=sys.stderr):
        if file.isatty():
            return TTYProgressPrinter(file)
        else:
            return NoTTYProgressPrinter(file)

class TTYProgressPrinter:
    def __init__(self, file):
        self._file = file

    def print_progress(self, message):
        # Image some fancy stuff with ANSI escape codes.
        pass

class NoTTYProgressPrinter:
    def __init__(self, file):
        self._file = file

    def print_progress(self, message):
        print(message, file=self._file)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. See my updated code example in the question. I forgot yo make `TTYProgressPrinter` and `NoTTYProgressPrinter` subclasses of `ProgressPrinter`.

Comment: I'm suggesting that you NOT make them subclasses.

Comment: In my real application, I have a lot of methods common to both implementation, so I'd have to add another base class.

Answer (score 0):

It's fine to define subclasses of a parent class (if such a design makes sense), but the parent class doesn't have to be responsible for creating the instances of the children.

```
import sys

class ProgressPrinter:
    def __init__(self, file):
        self._file = file

    def print_progress(self, message):
        raise NotImplementedError


class TTYProgressPrinter(ProgressPrinter):
    def print_progress(self, message):
        # Image some fancy stuff with ANSI escape codes.
        pass


class NoTTYProgressPrinter(ProgressPrinter):
    def print_progress(self, message):
        print(message, file=self._file)


def create_printer(file=sys.stderr):
    return (TTYProgressPrinter if file.isatty() else NoTTYProgressPrinter)(file)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an excellent[0] exercise to demonstrate what *metaclasses* can do:

```py
import sys

class ProgressPrinterMeta(type):
    def __call__(cls, file=sys.stderr):
        if cls is ProgressPrinter:
            if file.isatty():
                return TTYProgressPrinter(file)
            else:
                return NoTTYProgressPrinter(file)
        else:
            return super().__call__(file)

class ProgressPrinter(metaclass=ProgressPrinterMeta):
    def __init__(self, file):
        self._file = file

    def print_progress(self, message):
        raise NotImplementedError

class TTYProgressPrinter(ProgressPrinter):
    def print_progress(self, message):
        # Image some fancy stuff with ANSI escape codes.
        pass

class NoTTYProgressPrinter(ProgressPrinter):
    def print_progress(self, message):
        print(message, file=self._file)
```

[0]: *Excellent* if you're not going to use this in a project others are working on too.